# If I query a column with a foreign key on it do i need to join the referenced table?

Tags: sql-server

Lets say I have a table(table1) that has a column(column1) which has a foreign key on it referencing another table(table2). If all I want is the data in column1 do I need to join table1 and table2? So will the following code be sufficient:

```
SELECT column1
FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will be sufficient.
However, unlike what stan wrote in his comment, foreign key constraints are **not** for joins.
They are the database way of enforcing a part of data integrity called referencial integrity.
The meaning of a foreign key is that the database will not allow for 'orphan' records in the 'child' table - meaning that you can't insert records to the table if the value of the fk column does not exist in the referenced table.
This is also true for updates.
Also, you can't delete a record that has an fk referecing it.

Joins has nothing to do with fk constrains, though they often use the same columns that are used for the fk.You can join every table you want to every other table or view. In fact, some join types doesn't even have a join condition.